# Modifying unordered list from code behind

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am trying to dynamically add items to an unordered list from code behind and not sure how to do that correctly.

The html:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="myUL" runat="server">
   <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
   <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
   <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Code behind:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl li = Master.FindControl("myUL") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl;
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl anchor = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("a");
anchor.Attributes.Add("href", "~/Manager");
anchor.InnerText = "Manager";
li.Controls.Add(anchor);
```

That does work but the CSS is all messed up and does not use the CSS of the myUL control.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following changes to your code and all list items are appearing correctly:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl li = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("li");
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl anchor = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("a");
anchor.Attributes.Add("href", "~/Manager");
anchor.InnerText = "Manager";
li.Controls.Add(anchor);
myUL.Controls.Add(li);
```

This renders the HTML mark-up as:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="plcMain_myUL">
   <li><a id="plcMain_A1" href="/">Home</a></li>
   <li><a id="plcMain_A2" href="../../About">About</a></li>
   <li><a id="plcMain_A3" href="../../Contact">Contact</a></li>
   <li><a href="/Manager">Manager</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I used the code you provided, the following HTML was generated:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="plcMain_myUL">
   <li><a id="plcMain_A1" href="../../">Home</a></li>
   <li><a id="plcMain_A2" href="../../About">About</a></li>
   <li><a id="plcMain_A3" href="../../Contact">Contact</a></li>
   <a href="/Manager">Manager</a> <!-- Dynamically added item not wrapped around "li" -->
</ul>
```

I don't quite understand what you mean that the "CSS is all messed up". The only reason I can think of why the CSS is not working is either due to:

1) The missing "`li`" when the new HTML anchor is dynamically created.

2) You are using the `ID` attribute of the unordered list for styling. If this is the case, this will not work since .NET changes the ID dynamically on all server controls. Instead, use the `class` attribute.